# Как выровнять элементы в navbare

Tags: html, reactjs, scss

Пытаюсь сделать navbar по следующему ролику из ютуба: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3rofqqrTBE&ab_channel=OnlineTutorials для резюме которое тоже скачал с ютуба (теперь думаю понятно, что я новичок и мало понимаю)

Суть в том, что белый элемент (назначил белый цвет для контрастности) aka indicator прорисовывается вместе со всеми остальными элементами, но не совпадает с ними по местоположению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот куски кода отвечающие за данную анимацию

Navbar.jsx

```
<div className="Nav_container">
    <div className="logo">
        <img src={LogoGif} alt="my-gif" />
    </div>
    <div className="icons" >
        <ul className="nav_links">
            {navLinks.map((navlink, index) => {
                return <li class="list active" key={index}>
                <div class="indicator"></div>
                <a href={`#${navlink.links}`}>{navlink.icons}
                    <span class="text">{navlink.links}</span>
                </a>
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Navbar.scss

```scss
.nav_links {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    max-height: 50px;

    li {
        margin-left: 3rem;

        @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
            display: none;
        }
        &:hover {
            .text {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(-10px); 
                background: rgb(66,66,66);
                padding: 2px 7px;
                border-radius: 12px;
            }
            svg {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(30px);
            }
            .indicator {
                transform: translateY(30px);
            }
        }
        .indicator {
            top: 0px;
            border: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            background: rgb(29,31,35);
            background-color: #fff;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        .indicator::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 34px;
            left: 58px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: transparent;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: -14px -16px white;
        }
        .indicator::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 34px;
            left: -30px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: transparent;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 14px -16px white;
        } 
        a {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition: 0.5s;
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 100;
            &:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        .text {
            font-size: 0.8em;
            opacity: 0;
            margin-top: -25px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        }
        svg {
            display: block;
            font-size: 2em;
            transition: 0.7s;
        }
    }
}
```

Что нужно добавить, чтобы сместить позицию indicator в ровень с остальными элементами (думаю видно что иконки и текст расположены в ровень на одном уровне и только индикаторы смещены)

Comment: Сложно сказать в чем проблема, не имея полного рабочего примера, который можно было бы у себя попробовать. Но предположу, что проблема в иконках и в их размерах. Попробуйте установить одинаковый размер всем иконкам. Так же вы можете использовать средства разработчика (DevTools. Правую кнопку по элементам и "Просмотреть код" если используете Chrome). В нем посмотрите что смещает блоки. И чтобы проще было вам помочь, можете привести минимальный код, который можно было бы попробовать у себя. В вашем случае можно просто `html` код (не `jsx`, заменить например `navlinks.icons` на код `svg` файла).

Comment: https://github.com/Elijah-Prisyazhnyuk/portfolio_site/tree/main/DS_and_ML_side/react-portfolio-main

вот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `width: 70px;` к вашему `li`.

```scss
.nav_links {
    ...
    li {
        width: 70px;
        ...
    }
}
```

Результат:
[image: Результат]

P.s. Рекомендую внимательней еще раз пересмотреть ролик и правильно переписать стили. Именно по нему, я нашел одну из несостыковок с вашими стилями. Так же пользоваться инструментами разработчика в браузере. А еще  добавить `.gitignore` файл в папку с `React` приложением, хотя бы со строчкой `node_modules`. Чтобы при клонировании репозитория не приходилось скачивать все модули.

Comment: я не был уверен что без node_modules проект запуститься, я новичок в React. Отладчиком пользовался, но в голову не пришло попробовать поменять что-то в <li>

Спасибо за помощь!